Sequlize - Combine array contains operator with iLike
Following the example from here -  https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/querying/operators/#array-contains-operator
Post.findAll({
  where: {
    tags: { [Op.contains]: ['popular', 'trending'] },
  },
});

How can I combine iLike compare to it ?
For example -
I have this array of tags - ['foo', 'bar'] so I need something like -
Post.findAll({
  where: {
    tags: { [Op.containsWithLike]: ['%fo%'] },
  },
});

to retrieve this Post with this tags array because its elements are "iLike contains" to '%fo'
I rather a solution with any operator of Op rather than any Sequelize.literal(...) solution

Coul you show how it looks in plain SQL?
